# How do you use use GroupBy and Sum together in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a collection as such:

```
[[patient1,value1], [patient2,value2]]
```

For Example.
`x = [[1, 20.28], [1, 11.11], [2, 4.60], [2, 3.68]]`

I use `countBy` to get the the counts per patient as such:

```
def counts = x.countBy{patient, value -> patient}
```

I'm trying to get the sums per patient with no luck:

```
def sums = x.groupBy({patient, value -> patient }).collectEntries{p, v -> p:v.sum()}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Note: The overall goal here is to get the patient's average values which I use:

```
def avgs = sums.collect{patient, value -> (value / counts[patient]) }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the groupBy method the closure identifies what you want to group by, the list entries get filed under the grouped-by value:

```
x.groupBy { it[0] } // map entries by first entry in list (patient number)
```

evaluates to

```
[1:[[1, 20.28], [1, 11.11]], 2:[[2, 4.60], [2, 3.68]]]
```

The collectEntries method specifies what to make each map entry look like, given that each input to collectEntries has the patient number for a key and the list of pairs for that key for a value. So

```
x.groupBy {it[0]}.collectEntries {[(it.key): it.value.sum {it[1]}]}
```

evaluates to

```
[1:31.39, 2:8.28]
```

The average per patient would be

```
x.groupBy {it[0]}.collectEntries {[(it.key): it.value.sum {it[1]}/it.value.size()]}
```

evaluating to `[1:15.695, 2:4.14]`

For average of averages:

```
def avgs = [1:15.695, 2:4.14]
def averageOfAverages = avgs.entrySet().sum {it.value} / avgs.size()
```

Comment: How do I get the average of the averages now? I tried avgs.sum{it[1]} / avgs.size() but it caused No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.sum().

Comment: @ZacSol: map doesn't have a sum method, it only makes sense for things like list and set, so use map.entrySet(). added this to the answer.