# Group By and Sum using groovy and format to JSON

Tags: json, groovy

I am new to groovy and would like to sum the values of a map inside array list like below.

```
def list = [[field:A, amount:1000], [field:A, amount:2000], [field:B, amount:3000], [field:C, amount:4000]]
```

expected output:

```
list[
  {
     "field": "A",
     "amount": 3000 //Sum of items 1 & 2 in above list.
  },
  {
     "field": "B",
     "amount": 3000
  },
  {
     "field": "C",
     "amount": 4000
  }
]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use use GroupBy and Sum together in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404373/how-do-you-use-use-groupby-and-sum-together-in-groovy)

Comment: Working solution is here  https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5153513944383488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not a generic solution, but you can try something like this:

```
groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(list.groupBy{it.field}.collect{['field':it.key, 'amount':it.value.sum{it.amount}]})
```

Comment: Working demo for the above answe is here https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5153513944383488