# Groovy - average values in ArrayList by key

Tags: arraylist, groovy

I have this ArrayList

```
al.add([group:A, score:1])
al.add([group:B, score:2])
al.add([group:C, score:3])
al.add([group:A, score:4])
al.add([group:B, score:5])
al.add([group:C, score:6])
```

I want to get the average score for each group so that

```
ag[[group:A,score:2.5],[group:B,score:3.5],[group:C,score:4.5]]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I looked around to find a solution but didn't find any code example I can use so I am asking here.

Comment: I suggest starting here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgroovy%5D+groupBy

Comment: The example of the average here returns a NullPointerException

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404373/how-do-you-use-use-groupby-and-sum-together-in-groovy

Answer (score 1):

Following an example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404373/how-do-you-use-use-groupby-and-sum-together-in-groovy/34404845#34404845) and correcting it, this code returns the average:

```
al.groupBy {it.group}.collectEntries {[(it.key): 
                                       it.value.sum {it.score}/it.value.size()]}
```

Comment: You can also use `it.value.collect{it.score}.average()`, which I seem to find more to the point.